# How to make NetBeans IDE 6.8 show svn commit status (especially for "dirty" files)

Tags: svn, netbeans

I just switched from Eclipse to NetBeans IDE 6.8 for my PHP/Ajax development.  Eclipse always showed a little hard disk symbol over the file icon for files that were in sync with the svn repository, and an asterisk for files with changes that have not been committed.  Is there a way to see the commit status in NetBeans?  If not, what is your preferred way of recognizing which files to commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: NetBeans 6.8 provides File Status Information with Badges, Color Coding, and File Status Labels by default: see http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html#badges . **UPDATE END**

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversionAnnotation :

> **How Do I Display Subversion Branch/Tag Annotations?**
>
> Annotations are additional information that are displayed for each source file in the IDE. For example, if you turn on Subversion Status Labels annotations, you can see the branch and tag names for your files in the Projects and Files windows.
>
> You may do this by choosing *View > Show Subversion Status Labels* in the main menu.
>
> For more information, see: [How Do I Customize the Subversion Annotations?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversionCustomizeAnnotation)

Comment: Thanks, ax!  I didn't notice at first that the blue filenames indicated that the file had been modified.